# classNotfoundException during startup of ContextLoaderListener in wildfly 8.2 server

Tags: spring, resteasy, wildfly-8

Getting below error during server startup.

App Server: Wildfly 8.2
SpringVersion: 3.0.6.RELEASE
resteasy : 3.0.10.Final
resteasy-spring : 3.0.10.Final

Please advice how to resolve this.
spring-web jar is part of the EAR lib.

02:13:34,758 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."DisbursementsEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."DisbursementsWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."DisbursementsEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."DisbursementsWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "DisbursementsWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "DisbursementsEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/spring/SpringContextLoaderListener (Module "deployment.DisbursementsEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.resteasy-spring-3.0.10.Final.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.DisbursementsEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.resteasy-spring-3.0.10.Final.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 23 more

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Jar's need to be placed insider "lib" folder in EAR instead of META-INF/lib or just inside EAR.